# PKI authentication implementation in Apache

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, pki

I am trying to implement the Apache authentication through PKI digital certificates stored on token / smart card.

I'm using XAMPP 5.6.8.0-VC11 on a Windows 7 computer.

Following what I found searching the internet, I uncommented the following settings httpd-ssl.conf file in the Apache configuration:
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10

From there, access to https: // localhost, the browser (IE 11, Chrome 43 and FF 38) display the digital certificate of the screen (use an e-CPF in standard ICP-Brazil, stored in token) and requests the password.

After entering the password and press ENTER, the behavior in browsers is as follows:

In IE, I is shown a page with the message "This page can not be displayed".

In FF, is loading the page indefinitely.

In Chrome, you see the message "Authentication based on certificate failed" ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT and clicking on "details" appears:
"This server requires a certificate for authentication and did not accept the one sent by the browser. Your certificate may have expired or the server does not trust the issuer. Try again with a different certificate, if you have one, or you must obtain a certificate valid from somewhere else. "

Already tested several additional settings I found on the internet, but nothing works.

I have also changed the Windows Internet options regarding SSL and TSL, also successful.

I would like to figure out how to implement authentication with digital certificates for a more secure login system that esté in development.

Has anyone experienced this or know how to solve the issue?